# Use Spark RDD to Find Path Cost

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am using Spark to design a TSP solver. Essentially, each element in the RDD is a 3-tuple `(id, x, y)` where `id` is the index of a point and `x-y` is the coordinate of that point. Given a RDD storing a sequence of 3-tuple, how can I evaluate the path cost of this sequence? For example, the sequence (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (3, 1, 1) will give the cost `1 + 1 = 2` (from the first point to the second point and then to the third point). It seems in order to do this I have to know how exactly the Spark partitions the sequence (RDD). Also, how can I evaluate the cost between boundary points of two partitions? Or is there any simple operation for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any parallel processing, you want to put serious thought into what a single data element is, so that only the data that needs to be together is together.

So instead of having every row be a point, it's likely that every row should be the array of points that define a path, at which point calculating the total path length with Spark becomes easy. You'd just use whatever you would normally use to calculate the total length of an array of line segments given the defining points.

But even then it's not clear that we need the full generality of points. For the TSP, a candidate solution is a path that includes all locations, which means that we don't need to store the locations of the cities for every solution, or calculate the distances every time. We just need to calculate one matrix of distances, which we can then broadcast so every Spark worker has access to it, and then lookup the distances instead of calculating them.

(It's actually a permutation of location ids, rather than just a list of them, which can simplify things even more.)